# /proc/partitions recognition order confusion

Tags: linux

Other servers see sda、sdb、sdc sorted down like this, why does this one show this?

[image]

Comment: do not post text as pictures.

Comment: If you want it sorted in a particular order you should probably just pipe it through `sort`: e.g., `sort -k4 /proc/partitions`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there has been repeated hot-unplug and hot-plug operations? This might be a server system with FibreChannel or iSCSI SAN storage.

1. System starts up with disks `sda`..`sdh`.
2. Disks `sde`, `sdf` and `sdg` are hot-removed, with a proper `for i in e f g; do echo 1 > /sys/block/sd$i/device/delete; done` hot-remove procedure executed before the physical access to those disks is actually removed.
3. 3 new disks are added: they become the new `sde`, `sdf` and `sdg` to fill the holes in the alphabetical order, but because they are detected later than `sdh` was, they will be listed after it.
4. `sdf` is hot-unplugged with proper procedures, and a new disk presented in its place: this causes `sdf` to be listed after `sdg`.
5. 3 more new disks are added: since there are no "holes" in the allocated disk letters, they become `sdi`, `sdj` and `sdk`.

All of the above is done without rebooting the system.

After a reboot, `/proc/partitions` should again be in alphabetical order as expected... but the disks might not have the same letter positions as before the reboot. **This is why you use `UUID=` instead of device names, or use multipathing with WWIDs or persistent device names, and/or LVM, on systems using SAN storage.**

Comment: While that is a possibility, it is also true that for each disk, it is a race to get a name, a race to get a major/minor and a race to attach to the system.  with multiple cpus and multiple disks on different controllers it is very easy and common to see things out of order.    this is why it is extremely uncommon to see partitions used in /etc/fstab for anything but the boot disk.